# I want to surpress the number of a chapter but to have it's name on the header

Tags: header-footer, chapters, page-numbering

I'm writing a book. First chapter is the preface and I want it out of the content table and without a number, so I did `\chapter*{Preface}` which worked fine until I edit the headers of my book.

Because I've surpressed the preface's numeration with the asterisk, the header in it's pages write "CONTENT" on the top. Which I wanted to change and so I did:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Preface}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lhead{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{PREFACE}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
 blahblahblah
\end{document}
```

The result is not quite what I wanted, as I wanted the text "PREFACE" to appear in the same format as a `\leftmark` text would appear (all letters upper case with the first one bigger than the others) and, once I pass this chapter to the main `.tex` file, the header goes back to `\thispagestyle{heading}` which is pretty weird. All of my problems would be solved if I could just use `\leftmark` on this asterisked chapter or if there was another way to hide this chapter number and keep it from the contents table.

Comment: Try `\chaptermark{...}%`.

Comment: It appears a "CHAPTER 0:" but I liked it a lot. Do you know how to surpress this "chapter 0"? @JohnKormylo

Comment: Looked up the definition of \chaptermark.  You can use `\markright {\MakeUppercase{...}}` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `book` class you can use `\frontmatter` to start the front matter where chapters will not be numbered but will appear in the ToC. Then `\mainmatter` for the normal document style. There is also `\backmatter` for before things like a bibliography and index.

```
% chapheadprob.tex SE 575360

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
%\chapter*{Preface}
\chapter{Preface}
 blahblahblah

\lipsum[1-6]

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```